# php if first instance of variable int

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

if i have a mysql query that returns some values, these values are categorized by 'parent_id' there are roughly 3-5 values pr 'parent_id'. In my while loop, I only want to echo the first value from each 'parent_id'. How do i go about this?

something like "if this is the first time this variable has this value do stuff"

Comment: do you save the parent_id in a vector ? If the answer is yes then you might just echo parent_id_vector[0]..

Comment: Use a bool flag? It's hard to help since your question is kinda vague. Post some code if you can.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is difficult to understand and we don't like guessing. The more information you provide, the easier it is for us to help and the better answers you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the conditional to your while loop ...

```
$old_id = '';
while($row = $db->fetch_object()){
    if($row->parent_id != $old_id){
        //new parent_id
        $old_id = $row->parent_id;
        //... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks just was i was looking for!
Sorry if I wasn't clear, I knew there must be a simple solution to the question so i didn't figure I'd dig too much into it. For reference my loop ended up like this:

`$oldlimit = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      
  if($row['post_parent'] != $oldlimit){
  // Code to be executed
  $oldlimit = $row['post_parent'];
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the values in an array, and check if a new value is in the array.

```
$SeenValues=array();

foreach($AllValues as $Value){ //Or some other loop
    if (!in_array($Value, $SeenValues)){
        //Do something

        //Add new value to array
        array_push($SeenValues, $Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using `array_search()` instead of using `in_array()` and make a strong comparison like this `if (array_search($Value, $SeenValues)===false)`? May I ask you such?

Comment: @Lion: What would be the advantage?

Comment: @Lion: array_search returns the key that corresponds to the value that is found. Since I was not looking for a specific key and not looking in an associative array, I didn't use it.

Comment: Since I'm from Java background, I'm not much familiar with this thing that you mentioned. I just wanted to know about it. Thank you.